# Automatic keywords extraction(AKE) from a set of documents?

Tags: nlp, keyword, extract

Many algorithms are about extraction from a single doc. But I wanna know how can I extract keywords (or feature words) from a set of docs that they can represent the feature of this set of docs? Putting into all docs at a time to analyze could be too expensive. Is there some algorithm that I can process one doc at a time and then combine/calculate the results altogether to generate keywords of this set of docs?

Comment: If you at the end combine the results altogether why not process all docs upfront? Sounds like you are looking for **Topic Modeling**.

Comment: Please be more specific. What tools do you use etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to extract the keywords (several commercial APIs) along with their tf/idf score, do some cleanup and normalization. You'll need to do some testing and decide on an acceptable min threshold for the scores below which you throw out the words b/c they are not relevant.